# how to assign an id to an item when clicking on a link beside it in Django?

Tags: python, html, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm trying to assign an id to a CSV file's name so that when I click on a link beside I can access the CSV file itself on another web page to view it.

but I keep getting this error *'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'objects'*

**Note**: the CSV files are taken from a form and saved in a file on the PC, I'm trying to retrieve the file from the PC itself.

This is the **views.py**

```
def read_datasets(request):
    file  = request.POST.objects.get(id=id)
    # print(file)
    path = r"C:/Users/user/Desktop/Fault Detection App/Uploaded_Datasets/"
    # csv_file = request.FILES['file2']
    # csv_file = request.POST.get('file2')
    
    path1, dirs, files = next(os.walk(path))
    file_count = len(files)
    print(file_count)
    # dataframes_list_html = []
    file_names = []
    # file_name = csv_file.name
    for i in range(file_count):
        temp_df = pd.read_csv(path+files[i])
        print(files[i])
        # dataframes_list_html.append(temp_df.to_html(index=False))
        file_names.append(files[i])
        # print(dataframes_list_html)

    return render(request,'blog/view_datasets.html',{'names': file_names})
```

```
def one_dataset(request):
    path = r"C:/Users/user/Desktop/Fault Detection App/Uploaded_Datasets/"

    path1, dirs, files = next(os.walk(path))

    file_count = len(files)

    print(file_count)

    dataframes_list_html = []

    for i in range(file_count):
        temp_df = pd.read_csv(path+files[i])
        print(files[i])
        dataframes_list_html.append(temp_df.to_html(index=False))

    return render(request, 'blog/single_dataset.html', {'dataframes':dataframes_list_html})
```

and the **HTML File**

```
        <body>
            {% for dataframe in dataframes %}
                <div id="customers">
                    {{ dataframe|safe }}
                    <hr>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </body>
```

Comment: the error comes from here `request.POST.objects.get(id=id)` ... you appear to be trying to use it as a django queryset, but it is not, it is more like a Python dictionary. You should access it like in the lines you commented out below

Answer (score 1):

The `request.POST` is a dictionary. So you have to remove `.objects`

```
def read_datasets(request):
    file  = request.POST.get("...")
    ...
```